# VS Code Intellisense icons not correct?

Tags: python, icons, intellisense

In VS Code, Intellisense shows a "variable" icon for many functions such as, for instance, np.abs() as can be seen in the screenshot hereunder :

[image]

I'm new to Python but I would think that np.abs is a function, not a  variable, and as such Intellisense should show a "purple cube" which is the icon of methods and functions.

Do I miss something here or is it a bug with Intellisense ?